# Android Studio keeps on downloading Support Repository

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to get into developing using android studio, so I recently tried to run a simple login-activity app on it. Basically, what I did was just run the setup for a new android studio project, and selected loginactivity as my default screen. I configured the emulator and hit sync gradle, but it gave me the following response:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cqgz.png)

I downloaded the repository that was required and tried to sync the gradle again, but it again asked exactly the same thing! Please help!

my gradle file for the app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fyp.fingerpay"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version of the support library instead of using the "+" at the end?

Comment: @nope4561759 yes i've tried everything, doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have forgot to add maven repository in your app gradle file.
Try by doing these steps.
Open the build.gradle file for your application.
Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:
`allprojects {repositories {jcenter()maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}}}`
Avoid using + in your dependencies as it android studio will try to update dependencies every 24 hours.
Also replace compile by implementation for low APK size.